# PHP write in file

Tags: php

I want to write something in a textfile.

```
$myFile = "meinung.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Floppy Jalopy\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Pointy Pinto\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

when i want to execute this, it says "cant open file"

what did i make wrong?

Comment: Do you have write permissions in that directory?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the file/folder ?

Comment: You could try taking out the `die` and seeing what error it is giving you.

Answer (score 1):

Place

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
...
```

on top of your code to get error messages on screen or in your logfile (You know where your error logfile is, don't you?).

Set an absolute path to your file so that you really know in what directory the file is actually created to fix the filesystem permissions as noted in the comments.

Comment: Addition: With `$myFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/meinung.txt`; (or `$myFile = __DIR__ . '/meinung.txt';` since PHP 5.3) you'll get the absolute path.

Comment: @KingCrunch - `__FILE__` (with absolute path) is available since PHP 4.0.2; and: maybe he wants to place the content to some other directory than that of the script.

Comment: I know `__FILE__` is available since ... for a long time ^^ `__DIR__` is available since 5.3. Thats the reason you must use something like `dirname(__FILE__)` in versions <5.3. The hint with the directory is valid. So `$myFile = getcwd() . '/meinung.txt';` is probably better.